# DrawerLayout in main.xml with ScrollView

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview

Hi guys i have this layout...but if my phone is horizontal doesn't work the ScrollView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/sfondomain" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"     
        android:src="@drawable/icon_drawer" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView0"    
        android:src="@drawable/homelogo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:text="Prossimo Arrivo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/arrivi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"    
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" /> 



       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="327dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:text="Prossima Partenza"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/partenze"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"         
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />


       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/info"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:src="@drawable/info" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    </ListView>
```

but i don't know how put a ScrollView.
The layout works fine but when my phone in landscape doesn't scroll

I tried this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/sfondomain" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"     
        android:src="@drawable/icon_drawer" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"  
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView0"    
        android:src="@drawable/homelogo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:text="Prossimo Arrivo"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/arrivi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"    
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" /> 



       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="327dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:text="Prossima Partenza"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/partenze"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"         
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />


       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/info"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:src="@drawable/info" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" 
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
    </ListView>       


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is a logcat http://paste.ubuntu.com/9697890/

Comment: Hi, did you resolved this error? I also want to add scroll, but i'm getting   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.   in portraid mode also. Why is there a need to mention a specific height and weight?